# How to make primitive instance variable inside Spring @Service thread-safe?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, volatile

I have a Spring service class:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  private boolean flag = false;

  public void method1() {
    if(!flag)
    // do something
    flag = true;
  }

  public void method2() {
    if(!flag)
    // do something
    flag = true;
  }
}
```

It's obvious that the `flag` is not thread-safe. Without changing the scope of the service class, what options do I have to make it thread-safe? Can making it volatile solve the purpose?
I had searched for the solution before posting here but couldnt find one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run some logic only once if either of your methods gets invoked? If yes, can't you do that upfront with a @PostContruct? Otherwise, you can try using synchronized on the field, losing your multi-threaded benefits.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your objective is that you don't want `method1` and `method2` to execute at the same time, suggest using some kind of [utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) provided by JDK for concurrency control